# Move across image using Moviepy

Tags: python, moviepy

Using moviepy, I'm trying to make a video where it moves across an image.

Why isn't this working?:

```
image = ImageClip('image.png', duration=5)
image.set_position(lambda t: ('center', 50+t) )
image.fps = 30
image.write_videofile('video.mp4')
```

The outputted video is just a 5s video of the image (no movement)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two issues here.

#### Issue #1: ImageClip is not part of a composition

The documentation for [ImageClip.set_position()](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/ref/VideoClip/VideoClip.html#moviepy.video.VideoClip.ImageClip.set_position) says this:

> Set the clip’s position in compositions.
>
> Sets the position that the clip will have when included in compositions.

By "composition," it means a CompositeVideoClip. When an ImageClip is not part of a composition, set_position does nothing.

#### Issue #2: Return value of set_position is not used

`set_position()` has a somewhat confusing name. It does not actually set the position. It returns a copy of the Clip with the position set.

So this doesn't do anything:

```
image.set_position(lambda t: ('center', 50+t) )
```

instead, you need to do this:

```
image = image.set_position(lambda t: ('center', 50+t) )
```

#### Full corrected code

```
from moviepy.editor import ImageClip, CompositeVideoClip
image = ImageClip('image.png', duration=5)
image = image.set_position(lambda t: ('center', t * 10 + 50))
image.fps = 30
composite = CompositeVideoClip([image], size=image.size)
composite.write_videofile('video.mp4')
```

(Note: I also made the image movement larger so it would be more noticeable.)

<sub>(Thanks to the author of [this issue](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues/1402) for providing example code so I could figure out the problem.)</sub>